# How to make user select file in android studio using kotlin inside of a fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

Note that startActivityForResult() is depraciated. Most of the tutorials are outdated because of that.

You might tell me there is a forum for starting an activity in fragments but as a starter I don't know how to use it with file selection.

Comment: Selecting a file is exactly what the [official documentation uses as an example](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result).

Answer (score 1):

#### In Java,

```
private ActivityResultLauncher<String> resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new GetContent(),
    new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(Uri uri) {
            // Your code...
        }
});
```

In `onCreate()`

```
resultLauncher.launch("image/*");
```

#### In Kotlin,

```
private val resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->
    // Your code...
}
```

In `onCreate()`

```
resultLauncher.launch("image/*")
```

[Official Link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)